# Python & SqlAlchemy - Iterative build of a query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to, based on information passed into a RESTful webservice, use SQLalchemy to create a query that can optionally use filtering and sorting. I've been able to do this iteratively in Java, starting with just a simple query and adding filtering/sorting if needed, but I can't seem to figure it out in Python. Is there a way to do something similar to this:

```
q = BaseQuery([Image], session)

# Add pagination
q.paginate(page=page, per_page=per_page)

# If present, add filter
if filter is not None:
    q.filter(or_(func.lower(Image.description).like('%' + filter + '%'), func.lower(Image.name).like('%' + filter + '%')))

# If present, add sorting
if sortField is not None and sortDir is not None:
    if sortDir == 'asc':
        q.sort_by(asc(Image.sortField))
    elif sortDir == 'desc':
        q.sort_by(desc(Image.sortField))

for item in q.items:
    print(item)
```

This way, the query `q` is built iteratively based on what the UI requires, instead of having to do a ton of if statements to determine the query case it requires. It just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Any reason you're not re-assigning to `q` each time? `q = q.paginate(...)`, `q = q.sorted_by(...)` ?

Comment: Ah, is it really that simple? Just reassign it instead of trying to add to an existing object?

Comment: Where the operations chain, then yes: `something.filter(...).sort_by(...)` is no different than: `q = something.filter(...)` then `q = q.sort_by(...)`

Comment: From [Query API docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query): "It features a generative interface **whereby successive calls return a new Query object**, a copy of the former with additional criteria and options associated with it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Jon's comment above, this was way easier than anticipated. I simply needed to reassign (`q = q.filter()` for example) the variable:

```
q = BaseQuery([Image], session)

# If present, add filter
if filter is not None:
    q = q.filter(or_(func.lower(Image.description).like('%' + filter + '%'), func.lower(Image.name).like('%' + filter + '%')))

# If present, add sorting
if sortField is not None and sortDir is not None:
    if sortDir == 'asc':
        q = q.order_by(asc(getattr(Image, sortField)))
    elif sortDir == 'desc':
        q = q.order_by(desc(getattr(Image, sortField)))

# Add pagination
q = q.paginate(page=page, per_page=per_page)

for item in q.items:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Looks like if `sortField` is a string because you want to access a specific field, then you want `getattr(Image, sortField)` there instead of `Image.sortField` (which will try and access the `sortField` attribute - not a specific column name)

Comment: Yea, good catch. Was just doing pseudo-code, but might as well fix it. Thanks!

Comment: There is one gotcha on that, that it will barf if your iterative filter builder executes a join redundantly. In some of my apps I added a helper to keep track of which tables had been joined for that and it worked like a charm